# HoughCircles is not able to find Iris of an eye

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, hough-transform

I am trying to detect the Iris of an eye by using HoughCircles in OpenCV and Python. Before doing so, I am converting the image to grayscale and I am applying a Gaussian Blur. However, I am getting disastrous results. I am suspecting that the parameters of my HoughCircles call are wrong, however I can't seem to find any that work. Could it be that HoughCircles is not able to find the right circle on an image or are my arguments just wrong?

My code:

```py
eye = cv2.GaussianBlur(eye, (5, 5), 0)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(eye, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, eye.shape[0] / 2, param1=110, param2=20, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)
```

Original Image:

[image: original image]

Image after applying HoughCircles:

[image: image after hough]

---

Thanks to everybody for your help! I ended up dropping the idea of using HoughCircles for this task. Instead, I ended up using a CDF-approach as described here: [cdf-approach](https://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/31450154/IMECS2010_pp130-133.pdf?response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DIMECS2010_pp130_133_CDF.pdf&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWOWYYGZ2Y53UL3A%2F20200208%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200208T174612Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=3200c660a64061454d4251ccb2b3bd5ef6e09cb667ac2ca26388707c6cdbfcf9)

I think this solution works better since it's more robust to changes in lightning intensity and also less computationally intense (I think).

Comment: Houghcircle doesnt work properly in every image. My suggestion is that try to find it by using the other morphological methods via on edge detection.

Comment: Better if you show more of your code so your code can be tested by others and modified. Did you try changing the parameters?

Comment: You would need to convert the gray-scale image such that it has circles. You are trying to detect a disk, not a circle. Computing the gradient magnitude would be a good start.

Comment: Try thresholding and blob detection to solve the problem.